# WTP deployments without publishing fails

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, eclipse-wtp

I'm currently on Tomcat 7.0.21, JDK1.6.29, and WTP 3.3.1 (running on Eclipse Indigo.)  I'm not sure which version of M2E I'm running. My Project builds and deploys fine when I either do a mvn install and run Tomcat outside of Eclipse, or deploy to the server via WTP with the "Serve Modules without publishing" unchecked.

However, when I start the server via WTP with the no-publish box checked, Tomcat won't start successfully, failing with:

```
Dec 29, 2011 4:09:39 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig processAnnotationsJndi
SEVERE: Unable to process JNDI URL [jndi:/localhost/plutom-ws/WEB-INF/classes] for annotations
java.io.FileNotFoundException: jndi:/localhost/plutom-ws/WEB-INF/classes
    at 
org.apache.naming.resources.DirContextURLConnection.list(DirContextURLConnection.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsJndi(ContextConfig.java:1901)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsJndi(ContextConfig.java:1905)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsUrl(ContextConfig.java:1828)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1295)
```

If I manually create the classes directory, it then complains about classes/com  It seems like there's a conflict between a classloader and a file path resolve somewhere?

Comment: Why are you using no-publish? I mean isn't that the thing that's going to cause your classes to be published to the server?

Comment: It just means that it'll take my class files and deployments from the /target directory, as opposed to copy the actual war somewhere.  Copying the war means that any changes I make needs a stop and restart.  No-publish means that I can deal modify html/js/some class files without restart.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is unfortunately a known bug between Eclipse WTP and Tomcat 7. Here are the relevant Bugzilla entries:

[Tomcat 7 + Serve Modules without publishing fails to find classpath resources](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=374337)

[Really fix "Serve modules without publishing" with tomcat 7 by using the new VirtualDirContext of tomcat >=7.0.24](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=365813)

Apparently the fix is known, it just hasn't been applied yet. I guess it isn't a common use-case, because otherwise more people would be requesting it to be fixed. Its too bad, its a very useful feature.